# 2 Dropdowns Dependend on each other

Tags: pimcore

How would I create 2 DropDown Fields in a Object which are dependend on each other in the Pimcore Admin Backend Object Editing Interface?

for example:

> when DropdownA is USA
>
> DropdownB should show all States of USA
>
> when DropdownA is Germany
>
> DropdownB should show all Bundesländer of Germany

Answer (score 0):

For that you would need to develop a plugin which would provide a custom Object Field - which would in the end provide two dropdowns that are aware of each other. There is no clean solution to do what you want out of the box.

More information on plugin development:
https://www.pimcore.org/wiki/display/PIMCORE4/Plugin+Developer's+Guide